# PHP: не удаляет куки

Tags: php, mysql, cookie, сессия

Здравствуйте.

Установил куки через 
`setcookie("login", $login, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));`

Пытаюсь удалить куки через 
`setcookie("login", "", time() - (3600 * 24 * 30));`

Пытался и так 
`setcookie("login", "", time() - 3600);`

Но он не удаляет. Заходил в "сведения о сайте" в Хроме. В "использование файлов cookie" пишет рабочий куки **login** и после удаления куки пишет еще один куки с таким же именем и контентом *deleted*.

Устанавливал куки через переменную. Может нужно ставить куки через сессию?

Comment: @entithat,  удалит элемент `login` из массива `$_COOKIE`, но не куку из хрома ;)

Comment: Автор, пробуйте указать путь (и домен) при установке и удалении куки. И куки в хроме удалите, а то может там путь и домен с отличием есть.

Comment: вот так люди мучились :) -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401654/delete-cookie-in-php#32095533

Comment: @Visman, Может быть, хмм

Comment: присвойте куке null, еще как вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий вариант

```
setcookie('login', null, -1, '/');
```

В вашем примере **setcookie("login", "", time() - 3600);** второй параметр отправляется пустая строка, но все же значение некое.

Answer (score 0):

Либо же так:

```
setcookie('login', false, 1);
```